# How can I print out a single string from two sets of data?

Tags: python, selenium

I just started learning Python this week by working on a personal project. The goal of the script I'm working on is to essentially scrape the user's ID and comment from a given news article URL and put them together.

**So far it looks like this:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

articleurl = "http://news.nate.com/view/20170401n02609?mid=n1008"

articleid = articleurl[26:40]

print(articleid)

commentslink = "http://comm.news.nate.com/Comment/ArticleComment/list?artc_sq=" + articleid + "&prebest=0&order=O&mid=n1008&domain=&argList=0"
commentslink2 = "http://comm.news.nate.com/Comment/ArticleComment/list?artc_sq=" + articleid + "&order=O&cmtr_fl=0&prebest=0&clean_idx=&user_nm=&fold=&mid=n1008&domain=&argList=0&return_sq=&twitterAuth=N&connectAuth=N&page=2#comment"

print(commentslink)
print(commentslink2)

chrome_path = r"F:\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get(commentslink)

userlist = []
commentlist = []

usernames = (driver.find_elements_by_class_name("""nameui"""))
for userid in usernames:
    userlist += userid.text
    userlist.append(userid.text)
    print(userid.text)

comments = (driver.find_elements_by_class_name("""usertxt"""))
for comment in comments:
    commentlist += comment.text
    commentlist.append(comment.text)
    print(comment.text)
```

However, the console spits out the complete list of user ID's followed by the complete list of comments. I would like the user's comment to follow right after the user's ID. Right now, the console gives me this:

```
(1) bong****
(2) yang****
(3) hide****
... (continues through rest of user ID list)
(1) 어려보이고 싶어하는 순간 나이 먹은거래...
(2) 예능안보내는 이유가 있었네
(3) 드럽게 재미없네
... (continues through rest of comment list)
```

I've been trying to get it to look like this (*numbers are for clarity*):

```
(1) bong****: (1) 어려보이고 싶어하는 순간 나이 먹은거래...
```

I've been trying to work this out but nothing I've done has worked. I am thinking the problem is with the way the variables or for loops are coded. Are there any ideas on how to fix this?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

zip() function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

```
finalResult = list(zip(userlist, commentlist))
print(finalResult)
```

Comment: The console gave the same results and added a "<zip object at 0x03CD2760>" at the end.

Comment: @jrmymj, after getting the userlist and commentlist, use zip() and then print it out.

Comment: @jrmymj,    `print(list(zip(userlist, commentlist)))`

Comment: try open it with list(finalResult)

Comment: @jrmymj,  *zip() function returns a list of tuples,*--Not in python 3.x.

Comment: @7stud please have a look at python documentation. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: @jyotish: It's combining the two now but it's combining it character by character. For example, the console now returns "[('b', '어'), ('o', '려'), ('n', '보'), ('g', '이')" ... (and so on). Any idea what's going on here? Appreciate the responses so far.

Comment: @jyotish, Please have a look at the python documentation:https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip

Comment: @jrmymj,  Only do this: `userlist.append(userid.text)`  Don't use +=.  Experiment by comparing the difference:  `data = []; data += "hello"; data.append("hello")`

Comment: @jrmymj  remove "userlist += userid.text" and "commentlist += comment.text" and test again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `append()` and `zip()`:

```
userlist = []
commentlist = []

userlist.append("user1")
userlist.append("user2")
commentlist.append("Hello")
commentlist.append("Goodbye")

results = list(zip(userlist, commentlist))
print(results)

for user,comment in results:
    print("{}: {}".format(user,comment) )

--output:--
[('user1', 'Hello'), ('user2', 'Goodbye')]
user1: Hello
user2: Goodbye
```

Here's the difference between `append()` and `+=`:

```
data1 = []
data2 = []

data1 += "hello"
data2.append("hello")

print(data1)
print(data2)

--output:--
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
['hello']
```

You can think of a string as a list of characters.  `+=` instructs python to take every element of the list on the right hand side and add it to the list on the left hand side. On the other hand, `append()` adds one thing to a list--the argument.

If you end up with something like this:

```
userlist = [
    "user1",
    "user2",
    "user1",
    "user3",
    "user2",
    "user1"
]

commentlist = [
    "Hello",
    "Goodbye",
    "Yellow",
    "Blue",
    "Red",
    "Clouds"
]
```

Then you can do this if you want:

```
import itertools as iter

userlist = [
    "user1",
    "user2",
    "user1",
    "user3",
    "user2",
    "user1"
]

commentlist = [
    "Hello",
    "Goodbye",
    "Yellow",
    "Blue",
    "Red",
    "Clouds"
]

results = list(zip(userlist, commentlist))
sorted_results = sorted(results)
print(sorted_results)

for user, group in iter.groupby(sorted_results, lambda t: t[0]):
    print("{}:".format(user) )
    for tuple_ in group:
        print("\t{}".format(tuple_[1]) )


--output:--
[('user1', 'Clouds'), ('user1', 'Hello'), ('user1', 'Yellow'), ('user2', 'Goodbye'), ('user2', 'Red'), ('user3', 'Blue')]

user1:
    Clouds
    Hello
    Yellow
user2:
    Goodbye
    Red
user3:
    Blue
```

By the way, `"""nameui"""` is equivalent to `"nameui"` and `'nameui'`, so don't bother using triple double quotes.  Triple quoted strings are for multiline strings.

Also, unless you are doing more complex things, like clicking on links, you can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de) to scrape web pages.